# Was the word 'Warcraft' ever used in-universe?

Tags: names, warcraft

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warcraft#Video_games), the name 'Warcraft' was chosen for no particular reason other than that it sounded cool. The Wikipedia links to [this article](https://kotaku.com/how-warcraft-got-its-name-1838669881) that discussed the origin of the name in more detail.

I played all of the games, except for the original Warcraft: Orcs & Humans, and I cannot remember I ever saw any in-universe text in which the word 'Warcraft' was used. There is the 'World of Warcraft', but in-universe that world is called 'Azeroth'.

Was there ever any in-universe text in any of the games (or otherwise in the books), e.g. a dialogue or quest description that used the name?

Comment: I'd like to think the game was originally titled "CraftWar", and featured a tribe of origami enthusiasts taking on a collective of basket-weavers.

Comment: I've just done a search of 25+ WoW novels. Zero in-universe uses.